# How to add apt key with --recv-keys instead of --recv?

Tags: ubuntu, ansible

I want to install facebook osquery with ansible. The instructions for ubuntu are as follows:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys C9D8B80B
...
```

Unfortunately setting the id to `C9D8B80B` doesn't work. In tasks:

```
- name: Add repository key
  apt_key: keyserver=keyserver.ubuntu.com id=C9D8B80B state=present
```

The command fails:

```
TASK: [osquery | Add repository key] ****************************************** 
failed: [x.x.x.x] => {"cmd": "apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv C9D8B80B", "failed": true, "rc": 2}
```

The difference is `--recv C9D8B80B` vs `--recv-keys C9D8B80B`.

Which ansible `apt_key` option corresponds to `--recv-keys`?

Comment: Instead of `keyserver.ubuntu.com` consider using `pool.sks-keyservers.net`. Similarly to ntp, it's better to use always-available pool of servers rather than a specific server which can be down/broken/out of date.

Comment: @Mxx you're beyond me. Instructions come from https://osquery.io/downloads/

Comment: openpgp key servers work somewhat similarly to ntp servers. There is a pool of servers that are constantly staying in sync with each other and share the load. See https://sks-keyservers.net/status/ it doesn't matter what specific server you talk to, they all should have identical content. What they have is not wrong, but it's better to use the pool address to spread the load rather than always hammer ubuntu's server.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nevermind, it was a `sudo` issue. Presumably `--recv` and `--recv-key` and `--recv-keys` are the same option.

The full stack trace is:

```
stderr: gpg: requesting key C9D8B80B from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: no writable keyring found: eof
gpg: error reading `[stream]': general error
gpg: Total number processed: 0
```

To fix added `sudo: yes` to playbook.

Comment: With Ansible 1.9.4, I added `become: yes` to one play in a playbook.